# iOS Developer Program and/or Mac Developer Program

Tags: ios, macos, iphone-developer-program

I have written apps for both Mac and iOS, and I feel that they are close to being finished. I would like to publish them on their respective app stores... would I have to purchase a membership to both the Mac and the iOS Developer Programs for this? I really don't want to have to pay $198 if I can help it... Also, say I only get the iOS Developer Program: do I get anything else besides the ability to publish to the App Store and the iOS betas? For example, would I get access to the Mountain Lion beta? Similarly, if I joined the Mac Developer Program, would I get anything besides the ability to publish to the Mac App Store or access OS X betas?

Basically, is there any overlap between the two developer programs? Or are they two completely separate things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe they're completely separate.

Comment: In addition to getting access to betas and to the App Store, some technical information, including some extra forums where Apple employees will discuss prerelease information with you, also require the paid membership.

Comment: This question is about Apple's development program policies and pricing, and should properly be addressed to their customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since Apple merged two programs but anyway, you can purchase both programs for $99.

Comment: Or rather, there's not two programs for the price of one, but one program that now covers all four Apple platforms.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you have to pay twice.

Comment: That's disappointing... oh well. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you're successful, i'm sure you'll make back that $198 pretty fast haha.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you have to have both memberships

- If you have ios you cant have mountain lion
- if you have mac you cant have ios6 when it comes to beta

I have only iOS membership and i cant download the mountain lion